# How to pass value from text box in frame1.jsp to frame2.jsp after click submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, frameset

I have an index.jsp, frame1.jsp called and I need to pass the value in text box from frame1.jsp to frame2.jsp after click the Submit button to make database connection. I encountered error to do so. Please kindly help.

***index.jsp***

```
<frameset rows="18%,*">
          <frame src="frame1.jsp" name="frame1" scrolling="no">  
            </frameset>
```

***frameset1.jsp***

```
            <td width="15%"><b>
                    <font color="#FFFFFF" size="3">ADSL Number

                            <input name="ADSLNO" type="text" />

                     <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Confirm" />


                    </font></b></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
     </form>

 <frameset cols="100%,*">
                    <frame src="frame2.jsp" name="frame2">

            <noframes><body>No frame! </body></noframes>
            </frameset>
```

***frameset2.jsp***

```
</body>

              <%

                String ADSL = request.getParameter("ADSLNO");
                if(ADSL!= null)
                {
                String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://10.152.31.82/poller";
                Connection connection = null;
                String buffer = "<div class='divTable'>";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "dipadm", "dipadm123");
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select DT, PROFILE, DS_BW, SNR_DW, AT_DW, UCE, MODEL, CRC, RETRAIN from scanProfileData where ADSLNO='" + ADSL + "' order by DT DESC;");
                if (rs != null) {
                buffer="<div class='divRowh'><div class='divCellDT'>DATE/TIME</div>" ;
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellPROFILE'>PROFILE</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellBANDWIDTH'>BANDWIDTH</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellSNR'>SNR</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellATTENUATION'>ATTENUATION</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellCRC'>CRC</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellUCE'>UCE</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellMODEL'>MODEL</div>";
                buffer=buffer+"<div class='divCellRETRAIN'>RETRAIN</div></div>";

                while(rs.next()){
                buffer =buffer+"<div class='divRow'>"
                              +"<div class='divCellDTr'>"+rs.getString("DT")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellPROFILEr'>"+rs.getString("PROFILE")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellBANDWIDTHr'>"+rs.getString("DS_BW")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellSNRr'>"+rs.getString("SNR_DW")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellATTENUATIONr'>"+rs.getString("AT_DW")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellCRCr'>"+rs.getString("CRC")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellUCEr'>"+rs.getString("UCE")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellMODELr'>"+rs.getString("MODEL")+"</div>"
                              +"<div class='divCellRETRAINr'>"+rs.getString("RETRAIN")+"</div></div>";

                }
                }
                buffer=buffer+"</div>";
                response.getWriter().println(buffer);
                }
            %>
```

Comment: When i clicked the Submit button, no result display which should retrieve from the database.Should my index.jsp includes frameset2.jsp? For example: <frameset rows="82%,*"> 
          <frame src="frame2.jsp" name="frame1" scrolling="no">?

Comment: Do i need to create a function in frame2.jsp to include the database connection coding? So that frame1 can call frame2? Sorry i am beginner in HTML and JSP.